# Time multiplication per hourly wage

Tags: python, django

I am writing a code for a flight school management software. Basically, I have to enter the Departure and Arrival flight time, make the difference between the two times and make the multiplication for the hourly flight instructor wage.
My code is something like this:

```
time_1 = datetime.strptime('05:00:00',"%H:%M:%S")
time_2 = datetime.strptime('10:00:00',"%H:%M:%S")

time_interval = time_2 - time_1
print(time_difference)
```

The problem I am facing, basically, is how to make the multiplication between the time_interval variable and the hourly wage of the flight instructor.
Does anybody have any suggestion about that?

Comment: `((time_2 - time_1).seconds/3600)*wage`?

Comment: @not_speshal that should be `.total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `time_difference` variable is not defined.
For you to calculate the total wage:
You can take the difference of the times in seconds and convert it to hours(because you want to multiply it by hourly wage).
To convert from seconds, simply divide by 3600 (60*60)

To summarize, you can do:

```
(time_interval.total_seconds()/3600)*wage
```